# VP8 and WebM, not working in ffmpeg-php

Tags: php, command-line, ffmpeg

I need a help with ffmpeg-php and Ffmpeg.

**Ffmpeg:**

```
ffmpeg version 1.0.git
built on Oct  6 2012 01:54:50 with gcc 4.4.6 (GCC) 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-version3
libavutil      51. 73.102 / 51. 73.102
libavcodec     54. 63.100 / 54. 63.100
libavformat    54. 29.105 / 54. 29.105
libavdevice    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
libavfilter     3. 19.102 /  3. 19.102
libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
libswresample   0. 16.100 /  0. 16.100
libpostproc    52.  1.100 / 52.  1.100
```

**Ffmpeg-PHP**

```
FFmpeg 0.6.5
libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
```

**FFMPEG-PHP Command:**

```
ffmpeg -y -i /f1ccd3a27d36270492ce660da358b436.mp4 -t 99 -f webm /f1ccd3a27d36270492ce660da358b436.webm
```

**FFMPEG(SSH) Command:**

```
ffmpeg -y -i /f1ccd3a27d36270492ce660da358b436.mp4 -t 99 -f webm /f1ccd3a27d36270492ce660da358b436.webm
```

**FFMPEG-PHP Output:**

```
FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 29 2012 17:52:15 with gcc 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 59.94 (2997/50) -> 29.97 (30000/1001)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/f1ccd3a27d36270492ce660da358b436.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
  Duration: 00:04:16.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 650 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 108 kb/s
    Stream #0.1(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 480x360 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 539 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc
Output #0, webm, to '/f1ccd3a27d36270492ce660da358b436.webm':
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: 0x0000, yuv420p, 480x360 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: 0x0000, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.1
Encoder (codec id 146) not found for output stream #0.0
```

**FFMPEG(SSH) Output:**

```
ffmpeg version 1.0.git Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct  6 2012 01:54:50 with gcc 4.4.6 (GCC) 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-version3
  libavutil      51. 73.102 / 51. 73.102
  libavcodec     54. 63.100 / 54. 63.100
  libavformat    54. 29.105 / 54. 29.105
  libavdevice    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 19.102 /  3. 19.102
  libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
  libswresample   0. 16.100 /  0. 16.100
  libpostproc    52.  1.100 / 52.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/f1ccd3a27d36270492ce660da358b436.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
    creation_time   : 2009-12-23 02:00:55
  Duration: 00:04:16.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 650 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 108 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-12-23 02:00:55
      handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v08.13.2007.
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 539 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-12-23 02:00:55
      handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v08.13.2007.
[libvpx @ 0x2166e00] v1.1.0
Output #0, webm, to '/f1ccd3a27d36270492ce660da358b436.webm':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
    encoder         : Lavf54.29.105
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 200 kb/s, 1k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-12-23 02:00:55
      handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v08.13.2007.
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, flt
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-12-23 02:00:55
      handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v08.13.2007.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libvpx)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac -> libvorbis)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libvorbis @ 0x2167340] Que input is backward in time
frame= 2968 fps= 61 q=0.0 Lsize=    4464kB time=00:01:39.03 bitrate= 369.3kbits/s
video:3068kB audio:1319kB subtitle:0 global headers:4kB muxing overhead 1.662821%
```

**Error:**

```
Encoder (codec id 146) not found for output stream #0.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to encode to WebM, you need to compile FFmpeg with `libvpx` support. Your FFmpeg 1.0 has this, as can be observed in the `--enable-libvpx` compilation flag.

FFmpeg, starting with 0.6, [supports WebM](http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-0.6.release):

> This release features a lot of improvements that are relevant for HTML5 video.
>   […] This release supports Google's newly released
>   libvpx library for the VP8 codec and WEBM container.

Since you run 0.6.5, you could either recompile your existing old version with `libvpx`, or better yet, upgrade to a newer version that is not over two years old and probably has had hundreds of bugs fixed in the meantime. Mind you that the command line syntax has also changed quite significantly over the years.

Comment: And I just noticed [you were told](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12755211/435093) a couple of hours before you asked about this – so I'm curious as to why you've posted this question?